# Python: How to reform python list and print them line by line?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a file like this :

```
2.nseasy.com.|['azeaonline.com']
ns1.iwaay.net.|['alchemistrywork.com', 'dha-evolution.biz', 'hidada.net', 'sonifer.biz']
ns2.hd28.co.uk.|['networksound.co.uk']
```

Expected result:

```
2.nseasy.com.|'azeaonline.com'
ns1.iwaay.net.|'alchemistrywork.com'
ns1.iwaay.net.|'dha-evolution.biz'
ns1.iwaay.net.|'hidada.net'
ns1.iwaay.net.|'sonifer.biz'
ns2.hd28.co.uk.|'networksound.co.uk'
```

When I try to do that, instead of items of value domains_list, I get characters of domains. which means that the lists in the value of dictionary d are are recognized as a list but as a string. Here is an my code:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
f = open(file,'r')
start = time()
for line in f:
    NS,domain_list = line.split('|')
    s = json.dumps(domain_list)
    d[NS] = json.loads(s)


for NS, domains in d.items():
    for domain in domains:
        print (NS, domain)
```

example of the current result:

```
w
o
o
d
l
a
n
d
f
a
r
m
e
r
s
m
a
r
k
e
t
.
o
r
g
'
]
```

Comment: Funnz. How can one of your examples result into `woodlandfarmers`? Here must be something seriously wrong - probably the input you gave us...

Comment: `dumps` immediately followed by `loads` accomplishes nothing, it just returns the original value.

Comment: It is not valid json btw. It is single quoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing with json is not correct. `s = json.dumps(domain_list)` dumps the list into a string `s`. The `json.loads(s)` reads the string again, and then you range over the the string and print it, hence the single characters in the output. 
Try something like:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
f = open(file,'r')
start = time()
for line in f:
    NS,domain_list = line.split('|')
    d[NS] = json.loads(domain_list.replace("'", '"'))


for NS, domains in d.items():
    for domain in domains:
        print (NS, domain)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another one (assuming names.txt contains your data):

```
with open('names.txt') as f: # Open the file for reading
  for line in f:             # iterate over each line
     host,parts=line.strip().split('|') # Split the parts on the |
     parts=parts.replace('[','').replace(']','') # Remove the [] chars
     parts_a=map(str.strip, parts.split(',')) # Split on the comma, and remove any spaces
     for part in parts_a:       # for the split part, iterate through each one
         print '{0}|{1}'.format(host, part)  # print the host and part separated by a |
```

Note: You could replace the 4th and 5th line with parts_a=json.loads(parts) as well, assuming that the part after the | is JSON...

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to use `json` in this case as it doesn't solve your problem , you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) and [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) inside a list comprehension to create the desire pairs :

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> import ast
>>> sp_l=[(i.split('|')[0],ast.literal_eval(i.split('|')[1])) for i in s.split('\n')]
>>> for k in [zip(repeat(i,len(j)),j) for i,j in sp_l]:
...    for item in k:
...         print '|'.join(item)
... 
2.nseasy.com.|azeaonline.com
ns1.iwaay.net.|alchemistrywork.com
ns1.iwaay.net.|dha-evolution.biz
ns1.iwaay.net.|hidada.net
ns1.iwaay.net.|sonifer.biz
ns2.hd28.co.uk.|networksound.co.uk
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
import ast
with open(file, "r") as f:
    d = {k: ast.literal_eval(v) for k, v in map(lambda s: s.split("|"), f)}

for NS, domains in d.items():
    for domain in domains:
        print "%s|'%s'" % (NS, domain)
```

Or even just:

```
with open('file.xyz') as f:
    for thing in f:
        q, r = thing.split('|')
        r = ast.literal_eval(r)
        for other in r:
            print '{}|{}'.format(q, other)
```

Comment: If you see something in an answer which you think is an error, comment to the author please.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex solution:

```
import re

input = '''2.nseasy.com.|['azeaonline.com']
ns1.iwaay.net.|['alchemistrywork.com', 'dha-evolution.biz', 'hidada.net', 'sonifer.biz']
ns2.hd28.co.uk.|['networksound.co.uk']'''

for line in input.split('\n'):
    splitted = line.split('|')
    left = splitted[0]
    right = re.findall("'([a-z\.-]+?)'", splitted[1])

    for domain in right:
        print '{0}|{1}'.format(left, domain)
```

Outputs:

```
2.nseasy.com.|azeaonline.com
ns1.iwaay.net.|alchemistrywork.com
ns1.iwaay.net.|dha-evolution.biz
ns1.iwaay.net.|hidada.net
ns1.iwaay.net.|sonifer.biz
ns2.hd28.co.uk.|networksound.co.uk
```